# Navigate onScroll react-native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, navigation

I am unable to scroll horizontally using react native ScrollView.Also, I'm trying to trigger navigation onScroll.Basically what I am trying to achieve is to navigate whenever I scroll or pull button on the screen.What am I doing wrong?

MyFullCode:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  ScrollView,
  Button,
  View
} from 'react-native'

import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'
import Slider from 'react-native-slider'




class Home extends Component{

  static navigationOptions = {

   title:'Home'



  };

  render(){

    return(

        <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Home</Text>

        <ScrollView

            onScroll={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Login")}>
            >


<Button 
title="Login"
</Button>
</ScrollView>
        </View>
      )
  }
}

class Login extends Component{
   static navigationOptions = {  
   title:'Login'
  };
  render(){  
    return( 
        <View>
        <Text>home</Text>

        </View>
      )
  }
}

const App = StackNavigator({

Home:{ screen: Home},
Login:{ screen:Login}


});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },

  Button:{


  }
});

export default App
```

Comment: Why you want to login when you are scrolling the ScrollView? :D

Comment: no its just for reference. :)